# Convert a swift 2.3 alamofire class to swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

In this **alamofire** class the code was written in **swift 2.3** and when I try to convert it to new **swift 3.0** I'm getting errors. Would much appreciate if could help me setting this up.

A sample of a method is written here.

```
struct Singleton {
static let instance : APIManager = APIManager()
}

public class APIManager: NSObject {
public class var sharedInstance: Manager {
return Singleton.instance
}

let manager = APIManager()

override init() {

}

//MARK:====Login====`enter code here`

//MARK: methods

 func login(username: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (_ user: user, _ success: Bool) -> (), failed:@escaping (_ error: NSError) -> ()) -> Request {
 let urlRequest = "http://fladsrihvyg3ufjld.cvshowcase.com/ios/mobile/signup"// Create a URLRequest and pass to the method

 return manager.request(urlRequest)

  .validate()
  .responseJSON { response in
    if let error = response.result.error {
      failed(error: error)
      print(error)
      return;
    }
    let ok = ((response.result.value as! JSONDictionary)["success"] as? Bool)!
    let userJson = JSON((response.result.value as! JSONDictionary)["user"]!)

    let token = ((response.result.value as! JSONDictionary)["token"] as? String)!
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(token, forKey: UserDefaultKey.Token)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    let user = User(json: userJson)
    completion(user: user,success: ok)
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: What error ? Where ? Did you update Alamofire to the version that supports Swift 3 too?

Comment: i did add platform : ios, '10.0' and  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0' both. error has nothing to do with the pod itseems. the errors pops up in following areas.

1)public class var sharedInstance: Manager  //use of undeclared type 'Manager'

2) return manager.request(urlRequest) //value APIManager has no memeber 'request'

Answer (score 1):

Use new [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) pods for swift 3 no need to change whole code from swift 2.3 to Swift 3 and also need to update cocoapods varsion to 1.1.0 version.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target '<Your Target Name>' do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
end
```

And make request with the New Alamofire 4.0

```
 let parameters = ["action":"login", "email":"\(txtEmail.text!)" ,"password":"\(txPassword.text!)", "deviceType":"2", "devicetoken":"\(Session.gettingDeviceToken()!)"]

            Alamofire.request("\(CT.webAPI.localAPI.rawValue)", method: .post, parameters: parameters).validate().responseJSON { response in
                print("Response JSON: \(response.result.value)")
                //--------------------
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    self.successGetData(response: response.result.value! as AnyObject)
                case .failure(let error):
                    self.failedGetData()
                    print(error)
                }
            }
```

Comment: i did add platform : ios, '10.0' and pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0' both. error has nothing to do with the pod itseems. the errors pops up in following areas. 1)public class var sharedInstance: Manager //use of undeclared type 'Manager' 2) return manager.request(urlRequest) //value APIManager has no memeber 'request'

Comment: ok got it your point they have done some changes on their method its not a bug.